# firefox dosen't support div width

Tags: css, html, cross-browser

I have a problem with Firefox to show this: (But IE show correctly)

```
<div id="main_div" dir="rtl">
    <div dir="rtl">
          <div class="outer_div" dir="rtl"> Text! </div>
    </div>
    <div dir="rtl">
          <div class="outer_div" dir="rtl"> Text! </div>
    </div>
    <div dir="rtl">
          <div class="outer_div" dir="rtl"> Text! </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

======================================

```
body{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

div.main_div{
border: dotted; 
border-width: thin;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
background: #ffffaa;
border-color: #FFCC66;
width: 100%;
float: right;
}

div.outer_div{
float: right; 
padding-bottom : 5px;
padding-top  : 5px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
width: 33.3%;
border: dashed; 
border-width:thin  
}
```

Why this happened?! tnx

Comment: Firefox shows what? You just pasted some HTML with a missing `</div>` in it... is that the problem?

Comment: What version of FireFox? What version of IE?

Comment: Opera and Chrome work the same as Firefox so what does this tell us about IE? Never, ever, ever use IE as a reference for how things should work.

Comment: firefox V3.5 and IE V8.0

Answer (score 2):

You can't have pixel based padding when using % based sizing. Even IE doesn't get it right. If you look very closely (and change the size of the window), there is a white space to the left of your first div. When you add padding, it adds to the size of the div itself, so you have a div of 33.3% width + 20px (left-right). IE interprets this incorrectly and gives you a seemingly usable result. Firefox interprets this "as is" and you get the floated div.

What you need to do is apply padding to sub-divs inside your layout divs:

EDIT: Style Elements

```
body{ 
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px; 
} 

div.main_div{ 
border: dotted;  
border-width: thin; 
padding-bottom: 10px; 
padding-top: 10px; 
padding-left: 20px; 
padding-right: 20px; 
background: #ffffaa; 
border-color: #FFCC66; 
width: 100%; 
float: right; 
} 

div.outer_div{ 
float: right;  
width: 33.3%; 
border: dashed;  
border-width:thin   
} 

div.textformattingclass{
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; 
}
```

HTML Elements

```
<div id="main_div" dir="rtl"> 
    <div class="outer_div" dir="rtl"> 

          <!-- remove all content formatting from the style for the outer_div
               and place it in a style for this sub-div //-->

          <div class="textformattingclass">
              Some text! 
          </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="outer_div" dir="rtl"> 
          <div class="textformattingclass">
              Some text! 
          </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="outer_div" dir="rtl"> 
          <div class="textformattingclass">
              Some text! 
          </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: @user458975 - you haven't changed anything except the html portion. In order for this to work you must change the style to separate the padding from the width specification. I will edit my answer to expound.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing tag for the outer div, and also, no div should have the same ID on the page... You should be using the class attribute :)

Comment: i solved that (Enter missing div and id change to class) but still had the same problem!!